# Removing Borders from Collapsible Bootstrap Cards

Tags: css, html, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a set of cards that are revealed by a button on my website. When I reveal them, the cards (the information I'm trying to display) have a **small gray border** around them. I would like to remove this border, but setting `border: none;` in my CSS doesn't do it.

FYI: I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 (via CDN).

Code:

```
    <div id="skills" class="showcase-buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
        data-toggle="collapse" href="#skills-showcase" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="skills-showcase">
        Skills
      </button>

      <!-- collapsible content (skills) -->
      <div id="skills-showcase" class="collapse showcase-content justified-text">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="computer-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Computer</h3>
                <p>
                  We'll put some happy little leaves here and there. If we're going to
                  have animals around we all have to be concerned about them and take
                  care of them. As trees get older they lose their chlorophyll. This
                  present moment is perfect simply due to the fact you're experiencing
                  it. Let's make some happy little clouds in our world.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="design-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Design</h3>
                <p>
                  Put it in, leave it alone. Just let go - and fall like a little
                  waterfall. The more we do this - the more it will do good things to
                  our heart. Nature is so fantastic, enjoy it. Let it make you happy.
                  Trees grow in all kinds of ways. They're not all perfectly straight.
                  Not every limb is perfect. There are no limits in this world.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="problem-solving-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Problem Solving</h3>
                <p>
                  If these lines aren't straight, your water's going to run right out of
                  your painting and get your floor wet. And I will hypnotize that just a
                  little bit. You need the dark in order to show the light. We don't
                  really know where this goes - and I'm not sure we really care. I get
                  carried away with this brush cleaning.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Picture:
[image: website example picture]

Comment: What selector did you use to set the border to `none`? It will need to be more specific than the selector Bootstrap uses.

Comment: I just tried adding style="border:none;" to <div class="card card-body"> and the border is gone. I think your browser cached your CSS file. Try clearing your browser and let us know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what lead to my post being voted down? I'd rather be able to understand why my question isn't productive than just being left to know that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your cache not being cleared. If not you could try this and see if it does the trick:

```
.card {
    border: 0;
}
```

or:

```
<div class="card border-0">...</div>
```

Comment: For the record, I did both things. The CSS addition was necessary. I don't think I was adding the `border: 0` in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the border and the gray line around the skills button,it happens on click event.

```css
.card.card-body{ border:none; }

 .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus { box-shadow:unset !important;}
 
 .btn.focus, .btn:focus{ box-shadow:unset !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div id="skills" class="showcase-buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
        data-toggle="collapse" href="#skills-showcase" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="skills-showcase">
        Skills
      </button>

      <!-- collapsible content (skills) -->
      <div id="skills-showcase" class="collapse showcase-content justified-text">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="computer-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Computer</h3>
                <p>
                  We'll put some happy little leaves here and there. If we're going to
                  have animals around we all have to be concerned about them and take
                  care of them. As trees get older they lose their chlorophyll. This
                  present moment is perfect simply due to the fact you're experiencing
                  it. Let's make some happy little clouds in our world.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="design-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Design</h3>
                <p>
                  Put it in, leave it alone. Just let go - and fall like a little
                  waterfall. The more we do this - the more it will do good things to
                  our heart. Nature is so fantastic, enjoy it. Let it make you happy.
                  Trees grow in all kinds of ways. They're not all perfectly straight.
                  Not every limb is perfect. There are no limits in this world.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="problem-solving-skills">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <h3>Problem Solving</h3>
                <p>
                  If these lines aren't straight, your water's going to run right out of
                  your painting and get your floor wet. And I will hypnotize that just a
                  little bit. You need the dark in order to show the light. We don't
                  really know where this goes - and I'm not sure we really care. I get
                  carried away with this brush cleaning.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```